# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database in mac terminal only

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

in mac i want to create cronjob but when i run the php file with database i am getting error in terminal.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database
```

And In the browser run perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your PHP environment the same as your browsers PHP? command line php.ini can differ from, for example, your XAMP or other installed webserver

I would recommend checking this first

for me this did the trick

edit your **.bash_profile** file like

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/bin:$PATH
```

edit the path to your PHP bin from your XAMP

Answer (score 13):

check your port that mysql run .
in many cases mysql run in port 3306 but in my mysql it run in port 3308
and I add this:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "myDB","3308");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. My code was like this:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dB) or die("connection failed");
echo "connection success";
```

Problem: I did not indicate the port number.
Solution: I just included the port number, like below:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db,"3308") or die("connection failed");
echo "connection success";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have this code:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");
```

Try with creating new database called `myDB` in `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got similar error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'login.db' in D:\xampp\htdocs\login\functions\db.php on line 2
>   so i change [$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '**login.db**');] into 
>   [$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '**login**');]

Ii changed '`login.db`' to '`login`' and error disappear

Answer (score -3):

For me, the problem was the "Port number" **(on Step 3 of OpenCart 3.0.3.2 installation)** which was set as 3306 but in MySQL, it was showing as **3308** so I just changed the same and all went good.

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SssYQ.jpg)