# How do I resolve this problem? "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049):

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'art_gallery'

The database `art_gallery` is correctly imported and username is `root`, password is ``

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","art_gallery");
if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
    echo "Connection error".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Check this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979819/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1049-unknown-database-in-mac-terminal-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979819/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1049-unknown-database-in-mac-terminal-only)

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Comment: use phpmyadminj to check the database, especially the spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in this type of error there are two possibilities.

First is that there are some Spelling errors.
or
Secondly you have different servers installed on your machine.

Mostly it would be due to second cause, thus to identify those servers uniquely, you have to specify the port number in the localhost when connecting via mysql connect statement

Try
`mysqli_connect(“localhost:3308”,″root”,””,”dbname”)` (default is 3306) it can be changed.

The port number can be checked in the phpmyadmin at top center of panel as something like server:3308

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use  `new mysqli()` function instead of `mysqli_connect()` function. Hope I could help you.

Comment: There's not really any difference, `mysqli_connect` just returns a new `mysqli` object.